# Show that $\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt x}dx=\sqrt\pi$ by using $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Show that $\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt x}dx=\sqrt\pi\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$ by using $\;\;\;\;\;\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}$
How can I start? is subbing $y=x^2$ correct approach?

Comment: Let $x=\sqrt y$ and $dx=\frac{1}{2\sqrt y}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y = x^2$. Then, $dy/dx = 2x \implies dx = dy/2x = dy/2\sqrt{y}$.

Now, $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\ dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-y}}{2\sqrt{y}}\ dy$.